# How to find a unique set of closest pairs of points?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, geometry

`A` and `B` are sets of `m` and `n` points respectively, where `m<=n`. I want to find a set of `m` *unique* points from `B`, named `C`, where the sum of distances between all `[A(i), C(i)]` pairs is the minimal.

To solve this without *uniqueness* constraint I can just find closest points from `B` to each point in `A`:

```
m = 5; n = 8; dim = 2;
A = rand(m, dim);
B = rand(n, dim);
D = pdist2(A, B);
[~, I] = min(D, [], 2);
C2 = B(I, :);
```

Where there may be repeated elements of `B` present in `C`. Now the first solution is brute-force search:

```
minSumD = inf;
allCombs = nchoosek(1:n, m);
for i = 1:size(allCombs, 1)
    allPerms = perms(allCombs(i, :));
    for j = 1:size(allPerms, 1)
        ind = sub2ind([m n], 1:m, allPerms(j, :));
        sumD = sum(D(ind));
        if sumD<minSumD
            minSumD = sumD;
            I = allPerms(j, :);
        end
    end
end
C = B(I, :);
```

I think `C2` (set of closest points to each `A(i)`) is pretty much alike `C` except for its repeated points. So how can I decrease the computation time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a variant of the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm), which computes a minimum/maximum weight perfect matching. Create n-m dummy points for the unused B points to match with (or, if you're willing to put in more effort, adapt the Hungarian algorithm machinery to non square matrices).