# How to find a unique set of closest pairs of points in 1D?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, closest

My question is very similar to this one:
[How to find a unique set of closest pairs of points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41936760/how-to-find-a-unique-set-of-closest-pairs-of-points)

The only difference is that I am in 1D.

So, I have two sets of points (as I'm in 1D, we can see them as numbers between 0 and 1) A and B, each containing m and n element respectively, with m<=n

My goal is to find the set C, made of m DISTINCT points in B that minimize the sum of the distances [A(i), C(i)] 
If m = n, I can use wasserstein distance which has a nice 1D implementation
In 2D, I would use the hungarian algorithm, but it's quite expensive, and I hope that there is a quicker solution in 1D.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Thinking aloud:**

It is an easy matter to find, for every point in A, the two nearest points in B, on both sides. For this is suffices to sort A and B increasingly, and by a merge-like process you find the predecessor and successor in B of every point of A.

The cost of this process is O(NA Log NA) + O(NB Log NB) + O(NA + NB), where the last term can be absorbed.

The smallest sum will be achieved by assigning every point its nearest neighbor, among the left and right ones.

---

So far so good, but unfortunately the nearest neighbor might also be the nearest to a neighboring point in A, and the conflict needs to be arbitrated (one of the A-point must be assigned its other B-neighbor). In the worst case, this can cause cascaded conflicts.

So far, I fear that this problem is global and I see no better way than to try and resolve the conflicts in all possible ways and keep the best configuration. This process is exponential in the length of the sequences of conflicting points.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems to be better than the hungarian algorithm in the best cases, but worst in the worst cases, as your solution becomes of exponential runtime. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: @AdrienNivaggioli: as the Hungarian algorithm is polynomial-time, and my approach worst-case exponential, the latter should not be used at all. I guess that a better solution might be obtained by scrutinizing the Hungarian algorithm to check if by using the "sorting trick" the complexity can be lowered. At present time, I don't have enough insight in this algorithm to be of more help.

Comment: Thank you ! If I find a better solution, I'll come back to post it here!